# Cannot write file because it would overwrite input file even though in exclude list

Tags: typescript

I have a Basic Node.js Express 4 project in Visual Studio 2017. `utilities.js` is a legacy script file that I don't have time to convert to Typescript at this time. So I put it in a folder named `js` and excluded that folder. My solution structure is as follows:

[image]

and the complete `tsconfig.json` is as follows:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "exclude": [ "node_modules", "js", "public" ]
}
```

Compilation appears to be fine, ie I managed to clear all syntax errors, but there is a build error:

> Build: Cannot write '/js/utilities.js' because it would overwrite input file.

What is causing the error and how do I fix it?